# ValueError: could not convert string to float: '.' Python

Tags: python, csv, readline

So I am trying to make sure that all the values that I have in the csv file are converted into float. The values in each cell inside the csv file are just numbers like for example "0.089" "23". For some reason when I try to run the code it is giving the following error, " ValueError: could not convert string to float: '.' "
I can not really understand why the program is not reading the numbers from the csv file properly.

```
def loadCsv(filename):
    with open('BreastCancerTumor.csv','r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()[1:]
    dataset = list(lines)
    for i in range(len(dataset)):
        dataset[i] = [float(x) for x in dataset[i]]
    return dataset
```

Comment: The error message is pretty clear.  One of the lines you're converting contains just a decimal point.  It doesn't know how to convert `.` to a float.

Comment: By the way, did you mean to write `dataset[I]`?  What is `I` here?

Comment: `lines` is already a list, there's no need to write `list(lines)`

Comment: I just misspell that, it is [i]. I will try to replace the value that contains just the decimal point for 0. So by doing that I can run the program with no errors. Should that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never split the line into comma-separated fields. So you're looping over the characters in the line, not the fields, and trying to parse each character as a float. You get an error when you get to the `.` character.

Use the `csv` library to read the file, it will split each line into lists of fields.

```
import csv

def loadCsv(filename):
    with open('BreastCancerTumor.csv','r') as f:
        f.readline() # skip header
        csvf = csv.reader(f):

        dataset = [[float(x) for x in row] for row in csvf]
        return dataset
```

Comment: Panda's `read_csv` is also an option.